# Jboss 6.4 only works on localhost and how do i specify some other name instead of localhost

Tags: url, jboss6.x

I am able to access my application in jboss with `https://localhost/appName`

but how do i change the `localhost to whatever name i wanted` to have?

i would like to have it like `https://nameiwanted/appName`

I am using `jboss 6.4` and `windows 7 Professional`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

open jboss server at eclipse and check the check box in Server Behavior:

Listen on All interfaces to allow Remote and web applications

Answer (score 0):

Start server with `nameiwanted` like

> standalone.bat -b nameiwanted -bmanagement nameiwanted

make sure `nameiwanted` is bound to machine.